# Can I track download count of applications in playstore?

Tags: google-play

Does google playstore provide api's for tracking download count of my application ?

Answer (score 0):

See this [page](http://see%20https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870).
Commands & file formats for aggregated reports
Example:

```
gs://[developer_bucket_id]/stats/installs/installs_[package_name]_yyyyMM_[dimension].csv
```